# Unable To Get Public Property To Work In Custom Class

Tags: vb.net, properties

I have created a custom Class to which mimics a Textbox control but allows me to embed a button within this control.  Everything works fine normally.

However my problem is that I am trying to setup a Public Property that allows me to turn this button visible or not (well create it actually), but I cannot seem to work out why my property never gets set to True - meaning that since I've implemented this piece of code, my button is no longer drawn anymore.

I have the following code:

```
Public Class CustomTextbox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private m_EnableSearch As Boolean
    Private search_btn As Button

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        Initialize()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Initialize()
        search_btn = Nothing

        'Draw the buttons
        If EnableSearchButton = True Then CreateSearchButton() '<== This never equals True
    End Sub

    Private Sub CreateSearchButton()
        search_btn = New Button()        
        ...
        ...
    End Sub

    <Category("Appearance")> _
<Description("Enables the search button")> _
    Public Property EnableSearchButton() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.m_EnableSearch
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            Me.m_EnableSearch = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

If I take out the check for `EnableSeachButton = True` and just change it to `CreateSearchButton`, the button appears as expected.  However, even though I can see and change the EnableSearchButton property in the design view, it never seems to equal true when I step through the code.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `Initialize` is unneeded as this is not a form.  Since it is only created (Sub New) once, `m_EnableSearch` is always going to be False when created (has nothing to do with the property).

Comment: Just want to ask why your Initialize() if dont have a end if.

Comment: @MHHasnain  single line `If`s do not need them

Comment: It looks like you may need to use m_EnableSearch in the initialize method rather than EnableSearchButton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing.  Does `EnableSearchButton` actually ADD a button to the control or is it meant to toggle the `Enabled` state of said button?  To get the button to respond to the Property and toggle the enabled state, you need to set the button's state:

```
Public Property EnableSearchButton() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.m_EnableSearch
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Me.m_EnableSearch = value

        ' to create the button when the prop is set:
        If Value AndAlso search_btn IsNot Nothing Then
           ' create button
        End If

        If Value = False Then
            ' destroy button
        End If

        Me.Invalidate()
    End Set
End Property
```

Since you appear to be creating the button at runtime, you will have to add a check for cases when it is nothing.  Since the constructor only runs once and when created, there is no need to test the state of `EnableSearchButton`, just create it always.

If your Enabled property actually means something like AddButton to this TB, then just pass a Boolean in the ctor:

```
 Public Sub New(boolAddButton As Boolean)
     If boolAddButton Then CreateSearchButton() 
 End Sub
```

The way you have it, the backing field `m_EnableSearch` will always be true when the control is created.  Any prop setting you do in the IDE happens **after** the control is created which is the only place you have it set up to create the button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My purpose was to create the button at runtime 'only' if the property `EnableSearchButton` was equal to true.  Otherwise I was going to skip that function.

Comment: see edit: the ctor runs well before you ever access the property.  you need to either use the ctor, or create (and destroy) the button in the property setter

Comment: I would set it up to always add the button so you dont have a bunch if `If btn IsNot Nothing` cruft in there.  Then just add standard enabled and Visible properties to manage it.  If the button is invisible, it may as well not be there as far as the user is concerned.

Comment: Yes very true. I will modify my code and test now. Thankyou for all the comments and explaining how the property actually worked.  I wasn't aware that the property was set after the control was created.

Comment: think of it this way: `myTbCtl.EnableSearcher = true` this can ONLY be called/used *after* `myTbCtl` has been created (before that, it is Nothing).  The fact that you do it in the IDE is irrelevant, since the designer code cant set props until the host object exists either.

Comment: Thankyou for the explanation - that makes total sense when explained like that. I implemented your answer and it works very well.  Thankyou for taking the time the detail a solution and explaining the functionality - very much appreciated!